# Extra &/ampersand in json.dumps with python requests package GET Request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to perform a simple get request against a public api using the python`requests` package.
I am using requests 2.25.1 and python 3.6.

Unfortunately, there is an extra `&` preprended to the URL parameters that I cannot figure out where it comes from. Example code below with the wrong url and correct url removing the ampersand.

```py
import requests  
import json  

URL="https://search.rcsb.org/rcsbsearch/v1/query?json=" 
JSON={ 
"query": { 
 "type": "terminal", 
 "service": "text", 
 "parameters": { "value": "thymidine kinase" } 
  }, 
  "return_type": "entry"
} 

r=requests.get(url = URL,params=json.dumps(JSON, separators=(',', ':')))
```

`r.url` then is
`https://search.rcsb.org/rcsbsearch/v1/query?json=&%7B%22query%22:%7B%22type%22:%22terminal%22,%22service%22:%22text%22,%22parameters%22:%7B%22value%22:%22thymidine%20kinase%22%7D%7D,%22return_type%22:%22entry%22%7D`

which produces a 500 error.

if one changes `json=&%7` to `json=%7`the request works. How can I get rid of the extra ampersand?

`https://search.rcsb.org/rcsbsearch/v1/query?json=%7B%22query%22:%7B%22type%22:%22terminal%22,%22service%22:%22text%22,%22parameters%22:%7B%22value%22:%22thymidine%20kinase%22%7D%7D,%22return_type%22:%22entry%22%7D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're both trying to use the `params` keyword argument to `requests.get` **and** you're trying to build the parameter string yourself. Because of the `?` in your URL, the underlying url manipulation code assumes that there are already parameters and adds new ones using `&` (as in `someurl?param1=foo&param2=bar...`).

Pick one mechanism or the other, e.g.:

```
import json
import requests

URL="https://search.rcsb.org/rcsbsearch/v1/query"
JSON={
"query": {
 "type": "terminal",
 "service": "text",
 "parameters": { "value": "thymidine kinase" }
  },
  "return_type": "entry"
}

r=requests.get(url = URL,params={'json': json.dumps(JSON, separators=(',', ':'))})
print(r)
```